# My data is unicode until it gets pushed through JDBC and then it turns into question marks

Tags: java, jdbc

If I call my sproc directly with unicode characters, I can see those unicode characters in the table. I can read the unicode characters back out of my table.

In my application I can debug through the code and see that the data is unicode throughout the whole application. The last three lines are:

```
query = String.format("EXEC prcLibhashRefreshLog_i @Requester=\'%s\', @Libhash=\'%s\', @Product=\'%s\', @Reason=\'%s\'", user, libHash, service, reason);
```

I can see in the debugger that the data in "query" is still unicode. Everything is fine here. I can output 'query' to the page and it is unicode.

```
SQLStmt = DBConn.createStatement();
SQLStmt.execute(query);
```

After this step, the data in the database is "???????????". I know it's not SQL Server and I know it's not the sproc and I know it's not the data. How do I fix this?

EDIT: I forgot the 'N' before the string. How silly of me..

Comment: What JDBC driver are you using, what's your connection string, and what are the database collations involved? Can you *fetch* the data correctly from the database?

Comment: What's the encoding of your database? And what is your database? Maybe it can't handle Unicode. You may have to encode your data into the encoding if your database (for example `latin1` or `cp1252`, both of which I've had to deal with fit various databases)

Comment: I remember having some really painful character encoding issues when using JDBC with SQL Server for an internationalised website in the past. Sadly, it was so long in the past that i can't remember the details. I think the key thing, though, was that there was more than one character encoding in play - one for the database, but also one for the JDBC connection, i think?

Comment: Have a read about [International Features of the JDBC Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378857.aspx), and try setting `sendStringParametersAsUnicode` to `true` (although this is the default, so it shouldn't matter).

Comment: If this is MS SQL you're passing varchar characters to your stored procedure regardless of the encoding of the characters you're passing because you don't have a 'N' in front of your leading apostrophe. Try "query = String.format("EXEC prcLibhashRefreshLog_i @Requester=N\'%s\', @Libhash=N\'%s\', @Product=N\'%s\', @Reason=N\'%s\'", user, libHash, service, reason);"

Comment: You may also need to look at the way you're displaying the output.  For example, if you're using a command prompt that doesn't support unicode.  If you pull the data back from the database, using Java, and compare it to the original string, is it equal?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useUnicode=yes
```

in your connection string